# View stashed file contents without diff visualization

Tags: git

From [`git-stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) docs on `show` option (emphasis mine).

> Show the changes recorded in the stash entry **as a diff** between the stashed contents and the commit back when the stash entry was first created.

Is it possible to view the contents of a stash, not as a diff, but rather as raw file contents, in the same manner as `git show my-branch:path/to/my/file` would?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the command

```
git show stash@{0}:/path/to/my/file
```

This shows the contents of the file in `file` in `stash@{0}` not as a diff but as the full file.

Answer (score -1):

Unlikely.

Seeing how you could stash on one branch, then move over to another branch and apply the stash there. Stashes are stored as diffs internally by git, and the full file is not preserved or stored alongside the stash.

What *might* be possible with some arcane voodoo and maybe a sacrificial goat or three, is to give it both a stash and a commit (or branch) and show you how the stash would look applied on the version of the file on that commit. I doubt there's a built-in way to do that though.